# How to check if an ovalshape touches any other oval shape VB

Tags: vb.net

So I'm learning visual basic and I'm trying to make a timer that moves an ovalshape, and checks if touches any other ovalshape, where it will invert an integer. So i have this code, which works, but i was wondering if i could shorten it. If you could explain your code aswell since i am pretty new that would be great! Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick, Timer4.Tick
    Dim Pos As Integer
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape1.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape2.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape3.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape4.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape5.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape6.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape7.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape8.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape9.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape10.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape11.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape12.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape13.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape14.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape15.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape16.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape17.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape18.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape19.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape20.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape21.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape22.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape23.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape24.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape25.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape26.Bounds) Then
        Pos = -20
    Else
        Pos = 20
    End If
    bb.Top -= Pos
End Sub
```

Comment: One possible way to shorten it is to put all your OvalShapes into an array or List and use a loop.

Comment: Programming tip: *never* copy and paste code. Put it in a function or variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor the repeated code out into one method, and create constants for your values to better explain what they mean:

```
Shared Function GetIntersection(Shape first, Shape second)
    Const IntersectionValue = -20
    Const NonIntersectionValue = 20

    If first.Bounds.IntersectsWith(second.Bounds) Then
        return IntersectionValue 
    Else
        return NonIntersectionValue 
    End If
End Function
```

And then you would call it like this:

```
Dim Pos As Integer = GetIntersection(bb, OvalShape1)
```

This is an example of one of the important principles of good software design: [Don't Repeat Yourself (D.R.Y)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

The problem with your code, though -- regardless of whether you do it your way or the way I've proposed, is that you're never doing anything with the values -- you're overwriting the values with each subsequent operation.  For example:

```
If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape1.Bounds) Then
    Pos = -20
Else
    Pos = 20
End If

' you should at least do something with `Pos` assigned in the
' above if-else block before you overwrite it with the following if-else:

If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape2.Bounds) Then
    Pos = -20
Else
    Pos = 20
End If
```

The way it is, though, it's only ever going to take the value for `Pos` of the *very last* if-else block

```
If bb.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OvalShape26.Bounds) Then '...
```

So then what's the point of the other blocks that come before it?  They're just wasted overhead.

Comment: i realised this just as i finished asking the question that it would be overwritten, do you have any ideas of a way to do it?

Comment: what is an array? sorry im REALLY new.

Comment: @gomilksolgo -- I'd suggest you pick up a book on VB.NET for beginners.  Arrays are fundamental constructs in many programming languages, but they're too much to get into here.  Basically they're collections of values of the same type.

Comment: For a video on arrays, you can check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eG_eUsqaPtk&index=59&list=PLC601DEA22187BBF1) video. In fact, I'd recommend watching the entire series to get a better grasp on VB.NET as a whole. It's how I got started.